# NullPointerException received while accessing a variable

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer exception while accessing a variable. I have done the same code a couple of times and it works fine. But here Iam unable to figure out what exactly is going wrong. I understand there is a simple glitch somewhere. Thanks for any help!!

heres the code:

```
public void getSumsForPie(PieGraph pieGraph)
    {
    Cursor reportSumCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(total_cost) FROM food_table ", null);
            if(reportSumCursor!=null && reportSumCursor.getCount()>0)
            {
                reportSumCursor.moveToFirst();
                double getTotalFuelCostSum = reportCursor.getDouble(0); // Here the nullPointerException is thrown
                pieGraph.setFoodTotalSum(getTotalFoodCostSum);
            }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your reportCursor is null.

Comment: npe => a variable is null. A/ post stacktrace. B/ indicate which line causes the issue. C/ run in debug mode to view the content of the in-scope variables during the crash.

Comment: you call `reportCursor` when you probably mean `reportSumCursor`

Comment: Your reportCursor should be reportSumCursor

Comment: Yup I didnt realize I was calling a wrong cursor.. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if `reportCursor != null && pieGraph != null` on your if statement so you won't get null reference exception:

```
public void getSumsForPie(PieGraph pieGraph)
{
    Cursor reportSumCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(total_cost) FROM food_table ", null);

    if(reportSumCursor!=null && reportSumCursor.getCount()>0 &&
       reportCursor != null && pieGraph != null)
    {
         reportSumCursor.moveToFirst();
         double getTotalFuelCostSum = reportCursor.getDouble(0); // Here the nullPointerException is thrown
         pieGraph.setFoodTotalSum(getTotalFoodCostSum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 public void getSumsForPie(PieGraph pieGraph)
{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor reportSumCursor = db.query("SELECT SUM(total_cost) FROM food_table ", null);
        if(reportSumCursor!=null && reportSumCursor.getCount()!= 0)
        {
            reportSumCursor.moveToFirst();
            double getTotalFuelCostSum = reportSumCursor.getDouble(0);
            pieGraph.setFoodTotalSum(getTotalFoodCostSum);
        }
}
```